# How to center align text horizontally?

Tags: imgui

I am creating a text in ImGui. It automatically aligns right, how do I make just that one text align in the center?

```
ImGui::Text("Example Text");
```

I don't believe there is a function to do this. I know you can do it for a box or widget, but how would I for a simple text?

Answer (score 11):

```cpp
void TextCentered(std::string text) {
    auto windowWidth = ImGui::GetWindowSize().x;
    auto textWidth   = ImGui::CalcTextSize(text.c_str()).x;

    ImGui::SetCursorPosX((windowWidth - textWidth) * 0.5f);
    ImGui::Text(text.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add a solution for multi-line text to save the coffee time for someone.

```cpp
void TextCentered(std::string text)
{
    float win_width = ImGui::GetWindowSize().x;
    float text_width = ImGui::CalcTextSize(text.c_str()).x;

    // calculate the indentation that centers the text on one line, relative
    // to window left, regardless of the `ImGuiStyleVar_WindowPadding` value
    float text_indentation = (win_width - text_width) * 0.5f;

    // if text is too long to be drawn on one line, `text_indentation` can
    // become too small or even negative, so we check a minimum indentation
    float min_indentation = 20.0f;
    if (text_indentation <= min_indentation) {
        text_indentation = min_indentation;
    }

    ImGui::SameLine(text_indentation);
    ImGui::PushTextWrapPos(win_width - text_indentation);
    ImGui::TextWrapped(text.c_str());
    ImGui::PopTextWrapPos();
}
```

Comment: Hey cool function thx mate, but I do wonder, when I want to reposition the text-input with ur function with "ImGui.SetCursorPos(..)" it won't let me, it. just ignores it, I dunno understand why..

Comment: @Shpendicus I'm not sure what's happening in your case, but if you are on a Linux machine that's actually quite common. Some Unix systems just do not allow setting cursor positions programmatically, and most virtual machines will ignore it for security reasons. For example, you can never use Qt's `QCursor::setPos()` function in a VM.

Answer (score 2):

This [comment on a similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/442#issuecomment-716343835) could help, haven't tried it myself though:

```
void TextCenter(std::string text) {
    float font_size = ImGui::GetFontSize() * text.size() / 2;
    ImGui::SameLine(
        ImGui::GetWindowSize().x / 2 -
        font_size + (font_size / 2)
    );

    ImGui::Text(text.c_str());
}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to solve this issue with a table using the new Table API

Answer (score 1):

Although I've gone with the method others have listed here, there is another method using `Selectable`:

```
static bool test = false;
ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_SelectableTextAlign, ImVec2(0.5f, 0.5f));
ImGui::Selectable("Test", &test, 0, ImVec2(80,10));
ImGui::PopStyleVar();
```

The bad:

- Items have hover effects that cannot be disabled without making text gray.
- may have extra overhead

The Good:

- Easy
- NB: Unlike the other solutions, this one works in Table cells when table column auto-width is used. (double click on dividers)

Answer (score 0):

Well more performant way without std::string

```c
void TextCenter(const char* text, ...) {
    va_list vaList = nullptr;
    va_start(vaList, &text, );

    float font_size = ImGui::GetFontSize() * strlen(text) / 2;
    ImGui::SameLine(
        ImGui::GetWindowSize().x / 2 -
        font_size + (font_size / 2)
    );

    ImGui::TextV(text, vaList);

    va_end(vaList);
}
```